# Why hairs not growing in the vertex area

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups

Hair growing on the side but not on the top area. I have weight paint and made the vertex group yet no hairs grow on the vertex area. On the stomach and near nose. (I tried flip normal's, scale is 0) Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**Render view**

[image]

**Solid View**

[image]

**Vertex view**

[image]

**No group assign**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your hairs are growing but they are apparently combed down inside the mesh. You can use the puff-brush in the particle edit tools to get them back out. Seems like you are growing your hair with a global down direction, I'd rather recommend growing them normally and then grooming your model with the particle edit toolset.

Comment: Any option that the hair should be on the mesh and not go inside the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the hair is inside the mesh. Try brushing the hair in Wireframe mode so that you'll have an idea where you need to brush. Hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> and goto Particle Edit. Select "Puff" and click on the hair that is inside which'll make the hair stand up straight for every click of mouse (or) use "Comb" to drag the hair the way you want.